# C++ Time Without Date?

Tags: c++, time

What is the optimal way to work with time points without dates in C++?

I have timestamps without dates. The timestamps are for 24-hour military time, and without dates, time zones, or other information. The timestamps are stored as strings.

I need to accomplish two tasks:

1. Store the time data represented by the timestamps.
2. Calculate differences between times.

I am aware that C++ has libraries with time data structures. Some of these data structures include information about dates. If possible, I do not want to use those kinds of data structures, because my data does not include dates. I want functionality similar to that for time data structures in

- Boost.Date_Time
- chrono
- ctime

but without any storage of date or anything else but 24-hour military time (either explicit or implicit).

I want time point objects that store no information about date or anything other than 24-hour military time. I want to

1. Cast my timestamp strings to these objects.

then

2. Find differences between the resulting time points (durations between the time points).

What is the best way to accomplish this?

My ideal solution involves an already existing standard or Boost library, and avoids storing any information about date, time zone, or anything other than 24-hour military time. It is possible that I have overlooked that my need might be met by one of the libraries I already mentioned (viz. Boost.Date_Time, chrono, or ctime).

Comment: Storing a `duration` as the time since midnight, springs to mind

Comment: Either you want to use an existing library or boost, so what is the problem is using an existing struct provided by either and just zeroing the date information. If you are only dealing with military time. you have 86400 seconds per 24-hour period to deal with. So convert each time to seconds and you can differentiate between any two.

Comment: A 24 hour period sometimes have 86401 seconds (if a leap second has been added), 30 Jun 2015 had `23:59:60` (or `235960`) and 31 Dec 2016 also had one to name the latest.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: And leap seconds happen everywhere simultaneously, producing local time aberrations like 08:44:60.  Using anything with summer time, or really anything but UTC, for these purposes is madness.

Answer (score 4):

One idea is to create a custom `chrono` clock, perhaps called `time_of_day_clock` and then create a family of `chrono::time_point`s off of that.  Or perhaps you only need `seconds`-precision times (you weren't clear about that).  Here's all it takes to create a `seconds`-precision `time_point` on such a clock:

```
struct time_of_day_clock {};
using time_of_day = std::chrono::time_point<time_of_day_clock,
                                            std::chrono::seconds>;
```

Now you could create a couple of helper functions to cast between `std::string` and `time_of_day`:

```
// Assume t is of the form HH:MM:SS
time_of_day
to_time_of_day(const std::string& t)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto parse = [&t](auto i) -> int
        {
            return (t[i]-'0')*10 + (t[i+1]-'0');
        };
    hours h{parse(0)};
    minutes m{parse(3)};
    seconds s{parse(6)};
    return time_of_day{h+m+s};
}

// Format to HH:MM:SS
std::string
to_string(const time_of_day& t)
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto s = t.time_since_epoch();
    assert(s >= 0s);
    assert(s < 86400s);
    auto h = duration_cast<hours>(s);
    s -= h;
    auto m = duration_cast<minutes>(s);
    s -= m;
    string r = "00:00:00";
    auto print = [&r](auto i, auto j)
        {
            for (++j; i != 0; i /= 10, --j)
                r[j] = i % 10 + '0';
        };
    print(h.count(), 0);
    print(m.count(), 3);
    print(s.count(), 6);
    return r;
}
```

Now you have all of the tools to do something like this:

```
int
main()
{
    auto t1 = to_time_of_day("17:15:23");
    auto t2 = to_time_of_day("07:14:06");
    std::cout << "t1 = " << to_string(t1) << '\n';
    std::cout << "t2 = " << to_string(t2) << '\n';
    auto d = t1 - t2;
    std::cout << d.count() << "s\n";
    auto t3 = t2 + d;
    std::cout << "t3 = " << to_string(t3) << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
t1 = 17:15:23
t2 = 07:14:06
36077s
t3 = 17:15:23
```

This gives you type-safety:  *times of day* won't be confused with *durations*, but they *will* interoperate with a rational algebra.

Add as much error checking to the above as desired/required for your application.

There is one minor hiccup in the above plan:  The language lawyers could complain that the whole thing is undefined behavior because `time_of_day_clock` doesn't meet the chrono clock requirements.

The reality is that things will just work unless you try to call `now()` on `time_of_day_clock`, or use `time_of_day` with an algorithm that tries to do so (or tries to access a nested type of `time_of_day_clock`).  And if you accidentally do so, the result would be a compile-time error, not a run-time error, and not undefined behavior.

I consider the requirements on the `Clock` template parameter of `time_point` overly restrictive and will try to reduce them to what is *actually required* in a future standard<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> [Done](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2212r2.html).