# Parse time-of-day using C++20's chrono facilities / HH's date library

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-chrono

I am trying to parse a time-of-day string in the form of `"HH:MM"`, and receive back the nanoseconds since midnight.

So long as I provide a date **and a** time I can successfully parse it, eg:

(I am using Howard Hinnant's date library in lieu of C++20's chrono, as my std library (gcc 11.2) doesn't support this yet)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <date/date.h>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "1970-01-01 08:00";
    std::string format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M";
    std::istringstream ss(str);

    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::nanoseconds> t;
    ss >> date::parse(format, t);

    if (ss.fail()) [[unlikely]]
        std::cerr << "parse failed\n";

    std::cout << "ns=" << t.time_since_epoch().count() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

I see that `chrono` has a "time of day" class, [`hh_mm_ss`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/hh_mm_ss), but I don't see any associated parsing functionality.

Is it possible to parse a time-of-day string using a format, eg, `"%H:%M"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is to parse a `duration` such as `nanoseconds` and interpret that as "time duration since midnight":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <date/date.h>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "08:00";
    std::string format = "%H:%M";
    std::istringstream ss(str);

    std::chrono::nanoseconds t;
    ss >> date::parse(format, t);

    if (ss.fail()) [[unlikely]]
        std::cerr << "parse failed\n";

    using date::operator<<;
    std::cout << "time of day = " << t << '\n';
}
```

This involves:

- Truncate your string inputs to the desired information.
- Change the type of `t` to `nanoseconds`.

I used the streaming operator for `nanoseconds` and changed the formatting so that the output is:

```
time of day = 28800000000000ns
```

If you would rather get your original output without the `ns` suffix, then you can print out `t.count()`, and in that case there is no need for the `using date::operator<<;`.

---

If you want to get really fancy you can create your own custom `chrono::time_point` that has the semantics of "time of day".  That's usually overkill.  But if you would like to head that direction, here's some thoughts on it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56727183/576911.